# ARCore – How to set default scale for a Transformable node?

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I am using `Transformable` node and able to set minimum and maximum scale values. But I am using a model whose default size is much bigger so I have to use gestures to make it small.

How is it possible to set default scale value of a model / Transformable node?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i think you can use TransformableNode's setLocalScale method before it set a actual Renderable. like the code below

```
TransformableNode andy = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
      andy.setLocalScale(new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f));
      andy.setParent(anchorNode);
      andy.setRenderable(andyRenderable);
      andy.select();
```

I used 0.1f for x, y, z value, then it looks better

Comment: Note that the scale is bounded by the max/min values of the `ScaleController` of the `TransformableNode`. You can change it with `transformableNode.getScaleController().setMaxScale(maxScale)` and `transformableNode.getScaleController().setMinScale(minScale)`.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to get the `TransformableNode` scaled size in meters. Suppose I scaled a cube in y direction. Now I want to get the scaled size of it in unit meters. Please help me how to do that?

Comment: If the above solution doesn't work, you may have to set the minimum scale by doing the following.  In my case, the existing minScale was .75f

andy.getScaleController().setMinScale(0.1f));

Answer (score 3):

You can easily use this code for setting a default scale for a Transformable nodes:

```
TransformationSystem arTS;
arTS = MainActivity.getArFragment().getTransformationSystem();

TransformableNode node = new TransformableNode(arTS);
node.setRenderable(modelRenderable);
node.getScaleController().setMinScale(0.1999f);
node.getScaleController().setMaxScale(0.2000f);
node.setLocalScale(exhibit.getModelScale());
node.setLocalPosition(exhibit.getModelPosition());
//node.setParent(anchorNode);
node.setParent(sceneView.getScene());

node.getRotationController().setEnabled(true);
node.getScaleController().setEnabled(true);

sceneView.getScene().addChild(node);
node.select();
```

Comment: I get java.lang.IllegalStateException: maxScale must be greater than minScale when I do this. Are you sure MinScale and MaxScale can be equal?

Comment: In such a case you can set it like this: `.setMinScale(0.1999f)`.

Answer (score 0):

***imho*** easiest way to set default scale for node is to define scale attribute of 3d model in sfa-file

Answer (score 0):

In your .sfa file, change the default value of scale, then load the models and re-build the application